# Sublime Text indentation issue

Tags: jsp, jstl, indentation, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I encountered an indentation issue while combining html and jsp tags.

Steps to reproduce:

1. File > New File (Ctrl+N)
2. View > Syntax > Java > Java Server Page (JSP)
3. Paste the following code:

> ```
> <ul>
>    <c:if test="${a > 0}">
>       <li>a</li>
>    </c:if>
> </ul>
> ```

1. Select all the content (Ctrl+A) and run Ctrl+Shift+P > Indentation: Reindent Lines
2. The result is:

> ```
> <ul>
>    <c:if test="${a > 0}">
>       <li>a</li>
> </c:if>
> </ul>
> ```

Tested running Build 3047 under Windows 7 x64.

Any clues?

Comment: please summarize the issue **in the question**. Don't depend on external links remaining reachable.

Comment: It looks like a Sublime Text bug, you should report it on its issue tracker: http://sublimetext.userecho.com/ EDIT: Sorry, you've already done that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ST2 :

Open the html package and edit the `Packages/HTML/Miscellaneous.tmPreferences` file.

Replace the text with the one below. The below regex accepts basic jsp tags in `<c:if>` format & JSP comments. This will not format scriplets.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Miscellaneous</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>text.html</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>decreaseIndentPattern</key>
        <string>(?x)
        ^\s*
        (&lt;/(?!html)
          ([A-Za-z0-9]+(:[A-Za-z0-9]+)?)\b[^&gt;]*&gt;
        |--&gt;
        |--%&gt;
        |&lt;\?(php)?\s+(else(if)?|end(if|for(each)?|while))
        |\}
        )</string>
        <key>increaseIndentPattern</key>
        <string>(?x)
        ^\s*
        &lt;(?!\?|area|base|br|col|frame|hr|html|img|input|link|meta|param|[^&gt;]*/&gt;)
          ([A-Za-z0-9]+(:[A-Za-z0-9]+)?)(?=\s|&gt;)\b[^&gt;]*&gt;(?!.*&lt;/\1&gt;)
        |&lt;!--(?!.*--&gt;)
        |&lt;%--(?!.*--%&gt;)
        |&lt;\?php.+?\b(if|else(?:if)?|for(?:each)?|while)\b.*:(?!.*end\1)
        |\{[^}"']*$
        </string>
        <key>bracketIndentNextLinePattern</key>
        <string>&lt;!DOCTYPE(?!.*&gt;)</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**Restart Sublime Text**

Comment: Thanks. Could you please update the answer for ST3 if you were able to run it on ST3.

Comment: I modified this a little bit to fix a case with <% %> in a tag attribute and to handle curly braces. I am no regex expert, but it seems to work for my needs. Thanks for the starting point! http://pastebin.com/pwcysRLa