# sublime text 2 re-indent ionic tag incorrect

Tags: ionic-framework, sublimetext2

Anyone noticed that when re-indent with ionic or other tags in Sublime Text 2, it just align to the left rather than indent with tabs correctly. For example, this is what I expect Sublime Text 2 could done

```
<ion-view view-title="News">
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="news in news_list">
                <h2>{{news.title}}</h2>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

However, this is what it done actually after I clicked re-indent,

```
<ion-view view-title="News">
<ion-content>
<ion-list>
<ion-item ng-repeat="news in news_list">
<h2>{{news.title}}</h2>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I have tried built-in indentation, and want to try HTMLPrettify but it requires Node.js and I have no permission to install Node.js in my working PC. By the way, I have installed [Ionic Snippets - Sublime Plugin](https://github.com/PixelDropInc/ionic-snippets-sublime-plugin)

So, any suggestion?

Comment: I added this setting in Preferences->Key Bindings - User     { "keys": ["f10"], "command": "reindent", "args": { "single_line": false } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I did something similar to the answer at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691001/sublime-text-indentation-issue)

Need to edit RegEx in preference file